# ScrollPane and Panel Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jscrollpane

Look at the bottom of the code in the spaghettiFrame method. I want my JFrame to start scrolling down as I add more components to the contentPane panel. I know it has something to do with my Layout being set to null(absolute) but whenever I take it out it sets all my components in one horizontal line.

```
public class SpaghettiFrame extends JFrame{

    private static final AutoCompletion AutoCompletion = null;
    private AutoCompletion beta;
    private JSpinner Quantity_1;
    private JComboBox Part_1;
    private JPanel contentPane =  new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(contentPane);
    private JTextField Price_1;
    private JTextField Total;
    private JLabel lblTotal;
    private JTextField Building_1;
    private String value = "0";
    private String totalvalue = "0";
    private int loc = 1;
    private static String[] pricedatabase;
    private static String[] partdatabase;
    private static File pricefile = new File("DataBase/Price DataBase.txt");
    private static File partfile = new File("DataBase/Part DataBase.txt");
    private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy");
    private static Date date = new Date();
    private static File file = new File("Reports/" + (dateFormat.format(date)) + "Report.txt");
    private static PrintWriter info;
    ArrayList<JComboBox> part;
    ArrayList<JSpinner> quantity;
    ArrayList<JTextField> price;
    ArrayList<JComponent> next;
    ArrayList<JTextField> building;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        scanData();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SpaghettiFrame frame = new SpaghettiFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void scanData() throws Exception{

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(partfile);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          lines.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        partdatabase = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);

        Scanner scc = new Scanner(pricefile);
        List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (scc.hasNextLine()) {
          numbers.add(scc.nextLine());
        }
        pricedatabase = numbers.toArray(new String[numbers.size()]);
    }

    public void addComponent(AutoCompletion beta){

        Part_1 = new JComboBox();
        Part_1.setBounds(50, 28 + loc*40, 178, 20);
        for(int i=0; i <= partdatabase.length -1; i++){
            Part_1.addItem(partdatabase[i]);
        }
        part.add(Part_1);
        //AutoCompletion.enable(Part_1);
        Part_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                    totalvalue = "0";
                    for(int i=0;i<part.size();i++){
                        value = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(pricedatabase[part.get(i).getSelectedIndex()]) * (Integer)quantity.get(i).getValue());
                        totalvalue = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(totalvalue) + Integer.valueOf(value));
                        price.get(i).setText(value);
                        Total.setText(totalvalue);
                    }
            }
        });

        Quantity_1 = new JSpinner();
        Quantity_1.setBounds(287, 28 + loc*40, 41, 20);
        quantity.add(Quantity_1);
        Quantity_1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {      
              @Override
              public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                  totalvalue = "0";
                    for(int i=0;i<part.size();i++){
                        value = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(pricedatabase[part.get(i).getSelectedIndex()]) * (Integer)quantity.get(i).getValue());
                        totalvalue = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(totalvalue) + Integer.valueOf(value));
                        price.get(i).setText(value);
                        Total.setText(totalvalue);
                    }
              }
            });

        Price_1 = new JTextField();
        Price_1.setBounds(390, 28 + loc*40, 86, 20);
        Price_1.setText("");
        Price_1.setEditable(false);
        Price_1.setColumns(10);
        price.add(Price_1);

        Building_1 = new JTextField();
        Building_1.setBounds(5, 28 + loc*40, 35, 20);
        Building_1.setText("");
        Building_1.setEditable(true);
        Building_1.setColumns(10);
        building.add(Building_1);

        Total.setBounds(390, 68 + loc*40, 86, 20);
        lblTotal.setBounds(320, 68 + loc*40, 86, 20);

        update();
        loc++;
    }

    public void update(){
        for(JComponent j: part){
            contentPane.add(j);
        }
        for(JComponent j: quantity){
            contentPane.add(j);
        }
        for(JComponent j: price){
            contentPane.add(j);
        }
        for(JComponent j: building){
            contentPane.add(j);
        }

        contentPane.updateUI();
        contentPane.repaint();
    }

    public SpaghettiFrame() throws Exception {
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 492, 651);
        setContentPane(jsp);
        jsp.setViewportView(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        part = new ArrayList<JComboBox>();
        quantity = new ArrayList<JSpinner>();
        price = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        building = new ArrayList<JTextField>();


        JLabel lblBalanceCalculator = new JLabel("Balance Calculator");
        lblBalanceCalculator.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblBalanceCalculator.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblBalanceCalculator.setBounds(31, 11, 411, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblBalanceCalculator);

        Total = new JTextField();
        Total.setBounds(390, 68 + loc*40, 86, 20);
        Total.setEditable(false);
        Total.setColumns(10);
        Total.setText(totalvalue);
        contentPane.add(Total);

        lblTotal = new JLabel("Total:");
        lblTotal.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblTotal.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTotal.setBounds(320, 68 + loc*40, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblTotal);

        JButton btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
        btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    info = new PrintWriter(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                info.println("BALANCE CALCULATOR                " + (dateFormat.format(date)));
                info.println("");
                for(int i=0;i<=part.size()-1; i++){
                    info.println(String.valueOf(part.get(i).getSelectedItem()) + "  x  " + quantity.get(i).getValue() + "  =  " + price.get(i).getText());
                    info.println("");
                }
                info.print("Total: " + totalvalue);
                info.close();
            }
        });
        btnPrint.setBounds(43, 589, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnPrint);


        JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    totalvalue = "0";
                    for(int i=0;i<part.size();i++){
                        value = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(pricedatabase[part.get(i).getSelectedIndex()]) * (Integer)quantity.get(i).getValue());
                        totalvalue = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(totalvalue) + Integer.valueOf(value));
                        price.get(i).setText(value);
                        Total.setText(totalvalue);
                    }
                addComponent(AutoCompletion);
            }
        });
        btnNext.setBounds(353, 589, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNext);

        addComponent(AutoCompletion);
        update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JScrollPanes don't behave well with null layout using components, yet another reason to avoid null layouts like the plague. And if you don't use a null layout, your JPanel defaults to a FlowLayout, which is why everything is on one line.

The solution: don't use either but instead use a combination of nested JPanels, each using its own layouts to achieve your design goal.

---

**Edit**
For example, please look at these answers:

- [Layout with fixed height and variable width JButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522061/522444)
- [setLocation of Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208437/522444)
- [Java GUI button's label can't be seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15049176/522444)

And this tutorial:

- [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

---

**Edit 2**
As an aside, I wonder if what you're looking to create is a JTable that is displayed in a JScrollPane. This would hold and display tabular data well, which is what you're after, correct?

Comment: you got an example of that?

Comment: @LavaCreep: I have literally tons of such examples. Search for my Swing answers and you'll find many GUI's that use this sort of technique. Also Google the Swing layout manager tutorials and go through them.

Comment: @LavaCreep: you're welcome. Please also see links in edit to answer.